# object in componets и его реактивность

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть задача в компоненте отвязать от store объект. Но так чтобы он в самой компоненте был реактивен.

Если я при создании или монтировании компоненты создаю копию через `Object.assign` или `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` то копия образуется, однако данные перестают быть реактивным. Кто как реализовывает данную задачу?

ps. Как вариант, я могу в компоненте объявить в date сам объект и все его свойства пустыми, потом присвоить значения тогда все хорошо работает. Но не удобно когда объект большой, переписывать все его свойства в компоненте, немного не правильно как понимаю.

Comment: Тут похоже проблема не в отвязке, а в реактивности вложенности: `item` – реактивная, `item.id` – нет.

Comment: Да я понимаю, в том то и дело. Пока реализую только путем задания каждой переменной отдельно, что крайне не удобно когда в объекте 40 переменных

Comment: Тогда можно вписывать данные например через Object.assign / spread – `{...this.item, ...{title:'new title'}}`, не сильно грязно получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проверил уже на нескольких проектах и пришел к выводу делать так:
**component.vue**

```
 props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return {};
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editedItem: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    refresh() {
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.item);
      this.dialog = true;
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.refresh();
  }
```

В таком случае при вызове компоненты передаю старые данные или пустой объект

```
<component-form :item="old.item"></component-form>
```

`old.item` это сугубо пример можно передать пустой объект или ничего не передавать поставит сам дефолтом пустой объект.

При таком подходе все отвязывается и работает вполне корректно а при изменениях выполняю обновление в сторе через id объекта.

Answer (score 0):

Для клонирования советую [это](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep), `JSON` не все копирует, а `Object.assign` не глубоко.

Не совсем понимаю что значит

> в компоненте отвязать от store объект.

Если надо чтобы данные брало из store и они были реактивными:

> Как вариант, я могу в компоненте объявить в date сам объект и все его
>   свойства пустыми, потом присвоить значения тогда все хорошо работает.

Можно даже так:

```
  data () {
    // что нужно взять из store
    const fromStore = {
      info: this.$store.state.obj1,
      info2: this.$store.state.obj2
    }

    return {
      ...clone(fromStore),
      // обычное реактивное свойстов
      normalProperty: 'value'
    }
  },
```

`clone` - ваша функция клонирования

> Но не удобно когда объект большой, переписывать все его свойства в
>   компоненте, немного не правильно как понимаю.

Вроде все правильно. До этого Вы же тоже как-то вставляли данные из store, не думаю что намного больше когда получится.

Comment: clone вроде не доступна в date `'clone' is not defined`, я так понял это часть lodash

Comment: @RuslanSemenov я подразумевал что у вас должна быть функция clone которая клонирует)

Comment: @RuslanSemenov смотрите пример https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/aRvazm, там я навел еще более удобный способ чтобы не вызывать много раз clone

Comment: Так в Вашем примере вы тоже используете JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) Это тоже что и я делаю

Comment: @RuslanSemenov Вам надо использовать [lodash deppClone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep), в примере я не заморачивался с этим и сделал через JSON. Клонирование через JSON там отлично работает, поменяете у себя на lodash cloneDeep потому что это более лучшая практика и все.

Comment: Посмотрю lodash спасибо, за ответ. Если зайдет отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Читаем про `this.$set`

Например ваш случай:

```
this.$set(this.$data, 'someObject', { key: 'value' })
```

Comment: это чтобы не писать в data как null, но можно и сразу в data написать как я ответил. Также $set ставит для конкретного свойства, а у автора таких свойств много.

Comment: Все верно, но set может и изменить объект целиком. Сейчас проверю

Comment: `Vue.set(this.$data, 'item', this.inputItem)` сработало, но таким образом объекты остаются связанными, мне нужно отвязать его. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Я перестал понимать суть вопроса.
Надо отвязать объект от компонента, но чтобы он остался реактивным. Как это?

Comment: В компоненте клон в data насколько я понял.

Comment: `Vue.set(this.$data, 'item', this.inputItem)` не делайте так, если точно не знаете что делаете. Как на счет использования computed и watch?